# Unable to deactivate old non-compliant release on Production track

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-developers-console, android-app-bundle

I'm in a support loop situation with my Google Play app:

**Summary of Issue:**
We were pulled down due to a non-compliant APK we were using from PushWoosh. We subsequently updated the APK and pushed a new version on our production track. We did not realized we had an old inactive closed test track with an additional non-compliant APK so they denied our resubmission. We addressed this by iterating the release on both the production track and test track to insure both have new compliant versions of our app. However, because we had one iterated version on the production track from our first attempted resubmission we can now no longer flag the non-compliant version for deactivation. It only allows us to select the version previous for deactivation (which is the compliant initial resubmission). We are now stuck in this rejection loop where they are seeing the original non-compliant version as not flagged for deactivation, but we are unable to flag it. I've gone back and forth with their various support teams. They seem to always give me the same default responses. No one at google seems to understand the issue (or solution - which would be for them to just manually remove a couple versions from our production track).

[Our production track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk2pn.png)
I've included a screenshot of our production track in the console. As you can see Release 2.0.0 is the one I need to deactivate (red x), but when I add a new Release the only Release I can flag for deactivation is 27 (3.0.0) (Red bracket around it).

I'm desperate for help at this point and wonder if there is anyone who has advice? Have I missed something? The support channels I'm aware of have been exhausted and our app has been removed from the Play Store for two months.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic for stackoverflow. The only way to fix this is to talk to Google support.

Comment: Hey Philipvr, I understand your point. I guess I was hoping someone might have experienced something like this and might have a solution that I'm missing. Or perhaps a contact that I could leverage because I am not getting anywhere with Google Support.